# Not able to import Tkinter in Maya 2014

Tags: python, maya

I am using windows 7 and Autodesk Maya 2014.When i am trying to import Tkinter i am getting error.please tell me how to solve error given below ?
How to install any python package in Auto desk Maya 2014 ?

```
import Tkinter
```

**Error**

> Error: line 1: ImportError: file C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\lib-tk\FixTk.py line 65: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: Your shared library is propably 32bit library while maya's python interpreter is 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

I added a few Python modules to Maya with the "addsitedir-trick" explained at the end but not every python module will be playing nicely with Maya.

Python on Windows is built with Visual Studio 2008 Professional. Maya uses it's own Python interpreter but Autodesk builts Maya with another Visual Studio version. This can lead to problems if you insall python modules and try to use them with Maya. Beatuifully explained here (together with a the hard solution of compiling the wanted modules yourself):

http://p-nand-q.com/python/building-python-27-with-vs2010.html

**What you can try:** Install Python 2.7 on your Windows-box, install the module you want to access in Maya (eg with pip). Now in Maya add your system SitePackages (where you just installed the module to) to your Maya-Python-Interpreter SitePackages like so:

```
import site
site.addsitedir("/path/to/your/python27/Lib/site-packages")
```

Even cleaner solution would be to use a virtualenv instead of the global site-packages folder! (That's at least what i have done to get psycopg2 and requests play with Maya)

But as mentioned in the beginning of this answer there is a possibility that this may fail (with strange errors).

By the way: I highly recommend to use pyside instead of Tkinter if you want to do GUI stuff in Maya. Or the Maya-Wrappers preferably via pymel. (http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/ui.html)