# Import Error while importing Tkinter in Auto Desk Maya

Tags: python, maya

I am getting Error when i Import Tkinter in maya.Can anyone  explain me what is the meaning of this error and how to solve this ?

```
import Tkinter
```

**Error:**

```
ImportError: file C:\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py line 39: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: `from 32Bit import 64Bit as tk` always `tk is None` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724729/importerror-dll-load-failed-importing-tkinter)

Comment: what do you mean ? @dsgdfg

Comment: Check which `python` version on `MAYA` and `OS` !

Comment: If you would tell what you are trying to do, you will probably get a way better solution than Tkinter.

Comment: I want to make gui for maya using script editor @user1767754

Comment: You should definitely look into `pyQt` that's the native UI Maya is using as well. There are tons of examples out there for Maya PyQt UI's

Comment: i want to use it but  i am not finding any source where i can understand how to install pyqt  in maya 2014 @user1767754

Comment: You need `pyqt4` and `python2` You should read some tutorials how to set this up. It is a little involved, but once it is  running you will be happy using `PyQt`

Comment: thanks @user1767754

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to import Tkinter in Maya 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906065/not-able-to-import-tkinter-in-maya-2014)